# Commutation relations of the generators of the Lorentz group

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, commutator, lie-algebra

> $$ J^{\mu\nu} = i(x^\mu\partial^\nu-x^\nu\partial^\mu). \tag{3.16}$$
>   We will soon see that these six operators generate the three boosts
>   and three rotations of the Lorentz group.
>   To determine the commutation rules of the Lorentz algebra,
>   we can now simply compute the commutators of the differential
>   operators (3.16). The result is
>   $$ [J^{\mu\nu},J^{\rho\sigma}]=i(
>   g^{\nu\rho} J^{\mu\sigma}
>   - g^{\mu\rho} J^{\nu\sigma}
>   - g^{\nu\sigma} J^{\mu\rho}
>   + g^{\mu\sigma} J^{\nu\rho}
>   ). \tag{3.17}$$

This is from p.39 of Peskin&Schroeder's Quantum Field Theory book. It is written that (3.16) operators generate the Lorentz group. So, are the operators of (3.16) themselves Lorentz transformations?
Also, I cannot find a way to derive (3.17) from the definition (3.16). How does the metric $g^{\nu\rho}$ appear? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: How is it related to the appearance of the metric??

Comment: It appears because $\partial^\mu x^\nu = g^{\mu\nu}$.

Answer (score 3):

The metric appears because
\begin{equation}
\partial^\mu x^\nu = \partial^\mu g^{\rho\nu} x_\rho = g^{\rho\nu} \partial^\mu x_\rho = g^{\rho\nu} \delta^\mu_\rho = g^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
(write out the meaning of $\partial^\mu$ to see why this must be so).
Using this relation, it is straightforward to derive equation (3.17) from (3.16).

As to whether the $J^{\mu\nu}$ are Lorentz transformations, ZeroTheHero is entirely correct; using that
\begin{equation}
\exp(-i\omega_{\mu\nu}J^{\mu\nu}) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i\omega_{\mu\nu}J^{\mu\nu})^n}{n!} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 - \frac{i\omega_{\mu\nu}J^{\mu\nu}}{n}\right)^n , \tag{1}
\end{equation}
(with some restrictions on $\omega_{\mu\nu}, J^{\mu\nu}$) it can be shown that the generators $J^{\mu\nu}$ "generates" a representation of the Lorentz group through repeated multiplication/composition [cf. the last equality in (1)].

Answer (score 2):

Of course the $J^{\mu\nu}$ are not Lorentz transformations, no more than $L_x$ or $L_y$ are rotations.  The $J^{\mu\nu}$ are generators of the Lorentz group in the sense that exponential 
$$
\exp\left(-i \omega_{\mu \nu}J^{\mu\nu}\right)  \tag{1}
$$
is a Lorentz transformation, just like 
$\exp[-i(\zeta_xL_x+\zeta_yL_y+\zeta_zL_z]$ is a rotation.

As with the rotation group, where it is possible to factorize a general rotation as a product $\exp[-i\alpha L_z]\exp[-i\beta L_y]\exp[-i \gamma L_z]$, with $\alpha$ a function of $\zeta_x,\zeta_y,\zeta_z$ it is possible to write Eq.(1) in various factored form of course with different parameters as complicated functions of the $\omega_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Could you explain the commutation relations too?

Comment: What is there to explain?  You just power through the commutators much like you would for angular momentum.