# Commutation relation Lorentz Algebra

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, commutator, lie-algebra

[Related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/392415/), which I don't understand either. I think is easier to get the Lorentz group algebra as defined by [Maggiore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198520743),

$$
[J^{\mu\nu},J^{\rho\sigma}] = i(\eta^{\nu\rho}J^{\mu\sigma} - \eta^{\mu\rho}J^{\nu\sigma} - \eta^{\nu\sigma}J^{\mu\rho} + \eta^{\mu\sigma}J^{\nu\rho}),
$$

by using

$$
(J^{\mu\nu})^\rho_{\dot,\sigma} = i(\eta^{\mu\rho}\delta^\nu_\sigma - \eta^{\nu\rho}\delta^\mu_\sigma).
$$

This last expression is simpy the matrix representation of the generator $J^{\mu\nu}$. Then, for example, the first term in the commutatior should be like (since we are multiplying matrices)

$$
(J^{\mu\nu})^\alpha_{\dot,\beta}(J^{\rho\sigma})^\beta_{\dot,\gamma} = 
i(\eta^{\mu\alpha}(J^{\rho\sigma})^\nu_{\dot,\gamma} - \eta^{\nu\alpha}(J^{\rho\sigma})^\mu_{\dot,\gamma}),
$$

but this does not look at all like at least two terms in the commutation relation. Where am I wrong? What did I not consider?

Comment: If someone is interested in the calculation, I found it exactly [here](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/615/lects/lect06_2.pdf)